# Simple Drawable decorator doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I am doing this in an activity where `image` is an `ImageView`:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.somejpeg);

//only one of the lines below               
image.setImageDrawable(d); //works
image.setImageDrawable(new DrawableDecorator(d)); //does not work - blank image
```

Here is my drawable decorator:

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public final class DrawableDecorator extends Drawable {

    private final Drawable drawable;

    public DrawableDecorator(Drawable drawable) {
        this.drawable = drawable;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        drawable.draw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        drawable.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        drawable.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return drawable.getOpacity();
    }

}
```

I've overridden what I have to, just passing through to the decorated item, but what am I missing that is causing this to fail?

Note that the draw method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a few more essential overrides I should have passed through.

```
@Override
public boolean setVisible(boolean visible, boolean restart) {
    return drawable.setVisible(visible, restart);
}

@Override
public void setBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    drawable.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
}

@Override
public void setBounds(Rect bounds) {
    drawable.setBounds(bounds);
}

@Override
public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
    return drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
}

@Override
public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
    return drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
}
```